# Strange word spacing issue on some Microsoft websites

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, microsoft-teams

I have this strange issue where the Microsoft Sign In and MS Teams websites have very large word spacing, but other websites, including Office 365 sites like Outlook, render absolutely fine! I am on Arch Linux and I've tried this in Firefox and Chromium, in private and regular browsing, with hard refreshes, and I can't figure it out. I'm wondering if it's a font issue: is there some special font I need to install for these websites? I do have `ttf-ms-fonts` installed so I'm not sure what the cause could be. Any ideas?

Please see these screenshots:

[image: MS login page with huge word spacing]

[image: MS Teams page with huge word spacing]

Comment: Microsoft Login normal here; I do not use Teams. Try restarting your computer.

Comment: Can you try pressing Ctrl - 0 (zero) on these sites?

Comment: Yeah I've tried re-setting the zoom level and doing a hard refresh but no change :(

Comment: Try changing Scale (Settings, Display) to a lower scale (100)) and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry John I don't have that setting I am using Linux

Comment: You probably should add a Linux tag to your post.

Comment: Teams seem to use [Segoe UI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/design/design-teams-app-fundamentals#type). ttf-ms-fonts doesn't contain Segoe UI

Comment: I tried the Account Login in Ubuntu using Chrome and it was quite normal.

Answer (score 2):

Saaransh Garg's comment was the answer: I didn't have Segoe UI installed. I've installed the font now and everything looks great again. Thanks!